# Attempted import error: 'Picker' is not exported from 'selderee'. while using html-to-text npm package in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

> Attempted import error: 'Picker' is not exported from 'selderee'.

I got this error while I trying to convert html tags to text in the frontend. My code is given below. Please help me to get rid of this error.

```
import { convert } from "html-to-text";

const html = `<p>My name is Shahid.</p>`;
const text = convert(html, {wordwrap: 130});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uTlP.png)